# How to show a keyboard appear when click on UILabel in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I trying to show a keyboard when pressing on UILabel using NotificationCenter but the keyboard function is not calling and not showing the keyboard, I really need to show a keyboard appear when pressing on UILabel in Swift.

inside my class

```
MyClass : UIControl {}
```

but the keyboard function is not calling

```
private func _ini(){ let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(KeyboardDidShow(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil) } 

func KeyboardDidShow( myNotification: NSNotification){
 print("keyBoardUp") 
}
```

Comment: UIlabel does not conform the UIKeyinput, may I know what the concept you tried to show the keyboard

Comment: Thanks you so much, Now I changed UIlabel into UITextField, and created a UITapGestureRecognizer and calling a function and inside the function - self.selectedTextField.becomeFirseResponder() but now the keyboard is not appearing , still keyboard is invisible

Answer (score 2):

Keyboard only shows up for views which accept inputs e.g. `UITextField`, `UITextview` etc or the views which confirm to follow `UIKeyInput` protocol and implement **canBecomeFirstResponder**

Comment: Thanks you so much, Now I changed UIlabel into UITextField, and created a UITapGestureRecognizer and calling a function  and inside the function - self.selectedTextField.becomeFirseResponder() but now the keyboard is not appearing , still keyboard is invisible

Comment: You don't need a UITapGestureRecognizer on UITextField. When you tap on it it'll automatically appear, If you're on simulator press command + K to toggle it.